# Axios POST requests return empty array when using Promise.all

Tags: javascript, ajax, typescript, promise, axios

I do not get any statuses of the promises in my `requests` array when resolving with `Promise.all`.

What am I doing wrong here as I thought that using `axios` `post` method would return a promise?

```
  const doUpload = async (fileList: FileList) => {
    const requests: Array<void | AxiosResponse<any>> = [];

    Array.from(fileList).forEach(async file => {
      const formData = new FormData();
      const blob = new Blob([file]);
      formData.append(file.name, blob);

      requests.push(
        await axios
          .post(
            'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
            {
              ...formData,
            },
            {
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
              },
              onUploadProgress: (progressEvent: ProgressEvent) =>
                handleUploadProgress(progressEvent, file.lastModified),
            }
          )
          .catch(error => {
            handleUploadError(file.lastModified);
          })
      );
    });

    try {
      const data = await Promise.all(requests);
      console.dir(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: *"I do not get any statuses of the promises..."* What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jeremy's right that you have unnecessary `await`s in your code, but the primary problem is that you're hiding promise rejection by putting a `catch` handler on the promise from `post` and then letting that handler complete without either throwing an error or returning anything. That turns rejection into fulfillment with the value `undefined`.

Remove the `catch` handler (probably) or have it return something that you can use to know the `post` failed.

---

FWIW, here's an example doing the above and using `Array.from`'s mapping feature (since you're doing a mapping operation); see comments:

```
const doUpload = async (fileList: FileList) => {
  // Use `map`
  const requests = Array.from(fileList, file => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    const blob = new Blob([file]);
    formData.append(file.name, blob);

    // No need for `await` here
    return axios.post(
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
      {
        ...formData,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        onUploadProgress: (progressEvent: ProgressEvent) =>
          handleUploadProgress(progressEvent, file.lastModified),
      }
    );
    // No `.catch` here (or have one, but make it return something useful
  });

  try {
    const data = await Promise.all(requests);
    console.dir(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

If you need to call `handleUploadError` somewhere in there, you might consider using [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) (relatively new) rather than `Promise.all` and then calling that for any rejected promises in the array it gives you.

---

> ...when resolving with Promise.all.

Just a side note: Using `Promise.all` doesn't "resolve" the promises you pass into it. It just *observes* what happens with them. The promises will settle however they're going to settle whether you use `Promise.all` or not.

Some promise terminology that may be helpful:

- *fulfill* - To change a promise state from *pending* to *fulfilled* with a specific *fulfillment value*
- *reject* - To change a promise state from *pending* to *rejected* with a specific *rejection reason*
- *resolve* - To determine the eventual outcome of a promise, either directly (by fulfilling or rejecting it) or indirectly (by making its outcome depend on the outcome of another promise)

Comment: I think you made a typo, you probably mean `Array.from(fileList).map( file => {`

Comment: @JeremyThille - No, [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) accepts a second argument: a function that maps the entries being put into the array. So `Array.from(x, fn)` is like `Array.from(x).map(fn)` except it doesn't create a throwaway array (and the mapping function only receives `entry` and `index`, not `entry` and `index` and `sourceArray`). Mapping on the result was such a common use case it made it into the `Array.from` API. :-)

Comment: Oh, that's good to know, that's why I said I _think_ you made a typo, but I wasn't sure :)

Answer (score 2):

You are pushing resolved Promises to your array (`requests.push(await axios.post())`). Just push Promises without awaiting them(`requests.push(axios.post())`). Then `Promise.all` can do its job.

```
const doUpload = async(fileList: FileList) => {
    const requests: Array < void | Promise<any> > = [];

    Array.from(fileList).forEach( file => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        const blob = new Blob([file]);
        formData.append(file.name, blob);

        requests.push(axios.post(/* ... */ ));
    });

    try {
        const data = await Promise.all(requests);
        console.dir(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```